# When starting a sentence with an IUPAC name that starts with a number, do you capitalize the first letter?

Tags: nomenclature

When you have an IUPAC name that starts with a number, i.e. "3,5-dinitrosalicylic acid", but it's at the start of the sentence would you capitalize the first letter in the name? For example:

> 3,5-Dinitrosalicylic acid can reduce sugars with aldehyde or ketone functionality.

or,

> 3,5-dinitrosalicylic acid can reduce sugars.

Comment: See: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4275/capitalization-of-titles-starting-with-chemical-name-with-noncapitalizable-prefi

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the ACS style guide [[1, p. 240](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed083p1603.1)]

> Chemical names are not capitalized unless they are the first word of a sentence or
> are part of a title or heading. Then, the first letter of the syllabic portion is capitalized, not the locant, stereoisomer descriptor, or positional prefix.

Therefore, the following capitalization is correct:

> 3,5-Dinitrosalicylic acid can reduce sugars with aldehyde or ketone functionality.

#### Reference

1. *The ACS Style Guide: Effective Communication of Scientific Information*, 3rd ed.; Coghill, A. M., Garson, L. R., Eds.; American Chemical Society; Oxford University Press: Washington, DC; Oxford; New York, **2006**. DOI: [10.1021/ed083p1603.1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed083p1603.1), ISBN 978-0-8412-3999-9.

Comment: I don't have access, but the new version should be here: https://doi.org/10.1021/acsguide

Comment: I used the previous reference for the third "*offline*" edition since the quoted part can be found there, and I don't have access to the latest ACS SG either. Added woke BS aside (i.e. *Part 6: Inclusivity*), I would suspect the content would be pretty much the same. If anyone who has access to the latest SG, please feel free to make a correction.